# SQL Create a table

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CST_ID | TRC_TYPE | COLL_TYPE
2      | SH       |  NO
4566   | KA       |  WE
4566   | KA       |  TH
888    | EF       |  BV
44     | SC       |  BV    
44     | SC       |  BV
44     | KA       |  BV
```

i would like to table 1 to be result in the formation of table 2 such that the cells in TRC_TYPE(Transaction type) and COLL_TYPE(collateral type) become columns with counting how many times they have been performed by the customer without duplication of CST_ID(Customer ID).

```
CST_ID | SH | KA | EF | SC | NO | WE | TH | BV
2      | 1  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 1  | 0  | 0  | 0
4566   | 0  | 2  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 1  | 1  | 0 
888    | 0  | 0  | 1  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 1
44     | 0  | 1  | 0  | 2  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 3
```

table 2 represents the number of transactions and collaterals performed by a single customer with information taken from table 1.

Comment: The keyword you might be looking for is [PIVOT](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample.aspx) - did you try to write a query on your own?

Comment: Thank You, yes i tried to use CASE statements but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simple PIVOT but first you should make a subquery to union two columns with types in one using UNION :

```
SELECT CST_ID,
   SUM(CASE WHEN Type='SH' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as SH,     
   SUM(CASE WHEN Type='KA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as KA,
   SUM(CASE WHEN Type='EF' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as EF,
   SUM(CASE WHEN Type='SC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as SC,
   SUM(CASE WHEN Type='KA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as KA,
   SUM(CASE WHEN Type='NO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as NO,
   SUM(CASE WHEN Type='WE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as WE,
   SUM(CASE WHEN Type='TH' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as TH,
   SUM(CASE WHEN Type='BV' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as BV

FROM
(
  SELECT CST_ID,TRC_TYPE as Type FROM T
   UNION ALL
  SELECT CST_ID,COLL_TYPE as Type FROM T
) T1
GROUP BY CST_ID
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddel demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1abb6/2)</kbd>

Comment: You are amazing, ok what about counting the values of customer 44?

Comment: @Maram What's wrong with 44? Please see an example for your data in [SQLFiddel demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1abb6/2)

Comment: Sorry i am new in stack Overflow and i would like to tell you that i tried your answer and it worked with me, thank you so much :)